# Recovering mysql user table

Tags: mysql, users, permissions

I accidentally deleted the records from the mysql.user table on my mysql server. I didn't flush the privileges yet so I have the root privilege.

Is there a way to recover the table or to create the table from current privileges in memory?

(it's mysql 5 ubuntu 11.04)

Comment: Did you have binary logs enabled ??? If so, do you have all binary logs from the beginning ???

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid not. You're going to need to restore from backup.